# C# Socket Connect freezes app

Tags: c#, sockets

My application freezes when connecting using System.Net.Sockets;

```
m_Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

m_Socket.Connect(Host, Port);
```

It's freezing because either the host isn't accepting connections or the port isn't opened.

How can I fix this?

thanks

Comment: Do it on a background thread, or use BeginConnect/EndConnect to do it asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use BeginConnect and try to make the connection Asynchronously?